# Caching CSS files with a build script

Tags: javascript, css, performance

My question is if you concatanate css files together via a build script, will that css file be cached? or will is it re-downloaded every time one of the files is downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting CSS file will be treated just like any other static file. If your web server is set up to cache static files, it will be cached on the web server. If a users browser is configured to cache files, it will be cached until the web server says it has changed.